# What to do when the kitchen faucet's handle falls off just a little short of a year?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

[image]

I purchased a Forious kitchen faucet because it was selling well on Amazon. In just a little short of a year, its handle fell off. I tried to contact Forious over email, but they blew me off with some BS:

> "a new set of this faucet have been sent, you can see that we placed
> the order and have order ID."

They did not even ask for my shipping address... I replied to their email, they stopped responding.

What's the best way to reattach the handle? (solder? super glue?)

Comment: Contact Amazon & investigate your local online selling legislation.

Comment: They don't need your shipping address if they just created a re-order thru Amazon. Look in your Amazon orders to see if there's a new $0.00 order there.

Comment: Is "selling well on Amazon" a valid recommendation?

Comment: Sounds like you are *furious at Forious*.

Comment: @brhans I did not see a new order created.

Comment: Make contact with the seller through your Amazon account (not directly emailing them) so that you have a record of the event with Amazon. If they fail to resolve the issue then raise it with Amazon customer support.

Comment: @brhans Thanks brhans. Does that mean Amazon offers some sort of protection for customers if the manufacturer doesn’t want to resolve an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to re-attach your faucet handle with the broken tack-welds is to remove the socket from the shaft, and either weld it properly or braze/silver-solder it properly. Be sure to keep the correct alignment so you can access the set-screw through the handle-hole.

The more likely solution if you don't know how to, or are not equipped for, welding or brazing stainless steel is to clean it up as much as possible and then epoxy it into place. Be sure not to fill the inside of the socket with epoxy, or glue the set-screw in place. A "putty-type" epoxy may be better for this than a liquid/runny type. Be sure to give adequate cure time for full strength.

You can, of course, hire the welding done, but it may not make economic sense. If you know someone who will do it for a 6-pack, it might. Most commercial welding companies will price it sky-high because they don't really cater to consumer welding needs.

However, it is also likely as mentioned in comments that your new faucet is on the way, despite you not understanding how they can do that without asking for your address.

Answer (score 0):

They sell universal replacement handles at home Depot. They fit over the stem ,and there is a set screw that clamps them down.